# How to Render a view within a view without converting it to partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How to render a view (name.haml.html)file within a view.
It is possible to render a view within a view in Rails...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
<%= render :template => 'your view' -%>
```